# Problemas con expresión regular declaradas con new RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo una expresión regular que encuentra cualquier secuencia de caracteres comunes, como el *abecedario*, *números* en secuencia y *secuencias de caracteres en repetición*:

```
let charSequencesRegExp = new RegExp("(Abcd)+|(bcde)+|(cdef)+|(defg)+|(efgh)+|(fghi)+|(ghij)+|(hijk)+|(ijkl)+|(jklm)+|(klmn)+|(lmno)+|(mnop)+|(nopq)+|(opqr)+|(pqrs)+|(qrst)+|(rstu)+|(stuv)+|(tuvw)+|(uvwx)+|(vwxy)+|(wxyz)+|(012)+|(123)+|(234)+|(345)+|(456)+|(567)+|(678)+|(789)+|(890)+|(?<q>.+)(?=\k<q>+)", "gi");
```

Me detecta una coincidencia en tramos del abecedario:

```
console.log("Abcdefgh".match(charSequencesRegExp));
// sale [Abcd, efgh]
```

Y secuencias de números:

```
console.log("123456".match(charSequencesRegExp));
// sale [123456]
```

Pero cuando intento buscar una secuencia de caracteres que se repite como `"1a1a1a1a"`, **devuelve `null` cuando me debería devolver algo como `[1a1a1a]`**:

```js
console.log("123456".match(charSequencesRegExp));
// devuelve <null>
```

Probé mi expresión regular en una  **[página probadora de expresiones regulares](https://es.infobyip.com/regularexpressioncalculator.php)**, y ahí mi expresión regular *funciona a la perfección*, exactamente con los mismos `flags`, y *en el navegador no funciona como lo espero*.

¿Alguien sabe por qué no funciona adecuadamente mi expresión regular en mi navegador pero sí en un probador de las mismas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás utilizando la sintaxis adecuada que utiliza javascript para expresiones regulares. En javascript las expresiones regulares se declaran entre barras `/expresion/`.

La declaración de expresiones regulares mediante su constructor `RegExp()` tiene un gran problema, y es que recibe como parámetro dos strings, uno con la expresión regular y otro con las banderas. El problema viene de que en un string el caracter `\` representa un  escape, lo cual difiere de su significado en un RegExp. Para mitigar esto, si declaras una expresión regular utilizando un constructor, en donde vaya un `\` en la expresión regular deberás escribir `\\`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo con el que se obtiene el mismo resultado que en el sitio de pruebas utilizando la sintaxis recomendada para declarar Expresiones Regulares.

```js
let charSequencesRegExp = /(Abcd)+|(bcde)+|(cdef)+|(defg)+|(efgh)+|(fghi)+|(ghij)+|(hijk)+|(ijkl)+|(jklm)+|(klmn)+|(lmno)+|(mnop)+|(nopq)+|(opqr)+|(pqrs)+|(qrst)+|(rstu)+|(stuv)+|(tuvw)+|(uvwx)+|(vwxy)+|(wxyz)+|(012)+|(123)+|(234)+|(345)+|(456)+|(567)+|(678)+|(789)+|(890)+|(?<q>.+)(?=\k<q>+)/ig

console.log("1a1a1a1a".match(charSequencesRegExp));
console.log("123456".match(charSequencesRegExp));
```

Adicionalmente, te adjunto el mismo ejemplo utilizando el constructor, sustituyendo los caracteres de escape `\` de la expresión regular por `\\`. Como se observa, se obtienen los mismos resultados:

```js
let charSequencesRegExp =new RegExp("(Abcd)+|(bcde)+|(cdef)+|(defg)+|(efgh)+|(fghi)+|(ghij)+|(hijk)+|(ijkl)+|(jklm)+|(klmn)+|(lmno)+|(mnop)+|(nopq)+|(opqr)+|(pqrs)+|(qrst)+|(rstu)+|(stuv)+|(tuvw)+|(uvwx)+|(vwxy)+|(wxyz)+|(012)+|(123)+|(234)+|(345)+|(456)+|(567)+|(678)+|(789)+|(890)+|(?<q>.+)(?=\\k<q>+)","ig")

console.log("1a1a1a1a".match(charSequencesRegExp));
console.log("123456".match(charSequencesRegExp));
```

**Moraleja**: Como buena práctica y para evitar estos errores, utiliza siempre la sintaxis `/expresion/`.

Comment: ¡Funcionó! Es un poquito enredoso manejar las RegExp del segundo modo, pero ya iré aprendiendo. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Si, es súper engorroso, tienes que vigilar cada secuencia de escape, por eso en la documentación y en casi todos los sitios usan la sintaxis de barra, es muy buena práctica. Me alegra te haya ayudado. Saludos!